# Is it possible to disable `execute` in lieu of `exec`?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We've got an issue at the moment where we've got multiple query plans because some JDBC code uses `call` resulting in an `exec` statement, and other code uses `execute`. Is it possible to disable `execute` to nudge developers into only using `call`/`exec` (particularly since `call` is [faster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-how-to/running-stored-procedures-call-stored-procedures))?

Comment: Are you able to measure the performance difference between using EXECUTE and CALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

No, this is not possible. I'd add this as a code quality item to their code reviews.

That said, the root cause of the multiple plans is not the different call syntax. That could also happen with different `SET` options, etc. Instead look at query plans and the parameterization behavior, and the Query Store (if on 2016+) to see why you are getting different plans.

See also: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.